# MapView inside CollectionView cell doesn't display poly line Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, mkmapview

I have a `CollectionView` that displays all the tracked routes saved into `CoreData`. It's all working except for the missing `poly line` on the maps inside the cells. I thought it was because I forgot to import `CoreLocation` and assign it's delegate to the `ViewCOntroller' but it is still not showing up after adding it. In`cell`configuration I print the array from fetched object and it prints it correctly. In my main`MapViewController`i use the same process but here is not working as expected. Can you see what I'm missing out? Here's the code for the`ViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

class MyRoutesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var routeCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var myRoutesButton: UIButton!

    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Route>!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        routeCollectionView.dataSource = self
        routeCollectionView.delegate = self

        myRoutesButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        myRoutesButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
        myRoutesButton.layer.cornerRadius = myRoutesButton.frame.height/4
        myRoutesButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        configureFetchedResultsController()
    }

    func configureFetchedResultsController() {
        let context = AppDelegate.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Route>(entityName: "Route")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        do {
            try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
            print("fetched")
        } catch  {
            fatalError("failed to fetch entities: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let sections = self.fetchedResultController?.sections else {
            fatalError("no sections in fetchedResultController" )
        }
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Route Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! RouteCell
        let route = self.fetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath)

        cell.titleValueLabel.text = route!.name //RoutesArray.routeArray[indexPath.row].routeName ?? ""
        cell.distanceValueLabel.text = route!.distance //RoutesArray.routeArray[indexPath.row].distance ?? ""
        cell.durationValueLabel.text = route!.duration //RoutesArray.routeArray[indexPath.row].duration ?? ""

        do {
            let decodedCoordinates = try JSONDecoder().decode([CLLocationCoordinate2D].self, from: route!.coordinates!)
            print("decodedCoordinates are: \(decodedCoordinates)")
            let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: decodedCoordinates, count: decodedCoordinates.count)
            cell.map.add(geodesic)
            cell.map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(geodesic.boundingMapRect), animated: true)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    @IBAction func MyRoutesButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "newRouteSegue", sender: self)
    }


    // RENDER OVERLAYS
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKCircle {
            let renderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            renderer.lineWidth = 2
            return renderer
        } else if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange
            renderer.lineWidth = 3
            return renderer
        } else if overlay is MKPolygon {
            let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: overlay as! MKPolygon)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange
            renderer.lineWidth = 2
            return renderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
```

and for the `cell`custom class:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class RouteCell: UICollectionViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var durationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var durationValueLabel: UILabel!

 }
```

Comment: Is the `MKMapViewDelegate` set properly?

Comment: Add map over cell.contentview try this.

Comment: @vadian, I added the class code for the custom `cell` and I wasn't calling the `MKMapViewDelegate`there, so I added it. Nothing changed. if I start typing `map`autocompleete suggests `MapView`functions so I guess delegate is fine right?

Comment: @AnilKumar I don't understand your comment, can you please explain better?

Comment: @vadian. I found it.. I wasn't setting the delegate in cell definition..
I actually didn't think that was required..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vadian for point me in the right direction. I was missing to declare `cell` as `mapView delegate` in defining `cell`attributes.
so I just added `cell.map.delegate = self` in `cellForItemAt`function and now it works properly.
Thanks again.